# Mono fails to load a dll

Tags: mono, pinvoke, monodevelop

I am trying to load use a native shared library via P/Invoke. However, it won't load from under MonoDevelop. This is the console output with `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug` and `MONO_LOG_MASK=dll`:

```
Creating a V8Engine instance ...Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'V8_Net_Proxy'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/localhome/rryk/v8netmonolinux/Source/bin/Debug/libV8_Net_Proxy': '/localhome/rryk/v8netmonolinux/Source/bin/Debug/libV8_Net_Proxy: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/localhome/rryk/v8netmonolinux/Source/bin/Debug/libV8_Net_Proxy.so': 'libv8-x64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
```

However, the `libv8-x64.so` is located in the same directory as `libV8_Net_Proxy.so`:

```
/localhome/rryk/v8netmonolinux/Source/bin/Debug [mono-linux *]$ ls
libV8_Net_Proxy.so  V8.Net.Console.exe.config  V8.Net.dll.mdb                  V8.Net.Proxy.Interface.x64.dll      V8.Net.SharedTypes.dll.mdb  x64
libv8-x64.so        V8.Net.Console.exe.mdb     V8.Net.Proxy.Interface.dll      V8.Net.Proxy.Interface.x64.dll.mdb  V8.Net.SharedTypes.XML      x86
V8.Net.Console.exe  V8.Net.dll                 V8.Net.Proxy.Interface.dll.mdb  V8.Net.SharedTypes.dll              V8.Net.XML
```

Even more interesting is that the same very application loads the library just fine when executed from the console:

```
/localhome/rryk/v8netmonolinux/Source/bin/Debug [mono-linux *]$ MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug MONO_LOG_MASK=dll mono V8.Net.Console.exe

Creating a V8Engine instance ...Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'V8_Net_Proxy'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/localhome/rryk/v8netmonolinux/Source/bin/Debug/libV8_Net_Proxy': '/localhome/rryk/v8netmonolinux/Source/bin/Debug/libV8_Net_Proxy: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loaded library '/localhome/rryk/v8netmonolinux/Source/bin/Debug/libV8_Net_Proxy.so'.
```

I also checked that the same mono binary is used both on the console and in MonoDevelop. In fact I couldn't check which binary is used by MonoDevelop, but .NET Runtimes section in the settings displays version 3.0.12. I only have one Mono binary in the system which has this version and it is the one used on the command line by default (as it's listed first in `whichis`):

```
~$ whereis mono
mono: /usr/bin/mono /etc/mono /usr/lib/mono /usr/bin/X11/mono /usr/local/bin/mono /usr/local/etc/mono /usr/local/lib/mono /usr/share/mono /usr/share/man/man1/mono.1.gz
```

What can cause the difference? Why doesn't Mono find the `libv8-x64.so`, which is located in the same directory?

Comment: I assume that libv8-x64.so is a dependency of libV8_Net_Proxy.so so native linker can be causing troubles. Could you please try to copy libv8-x64.so to /usr/lib then execute `ldconfig` as root and try again?

Comment: Thanks jariq, copying `libv8-x64.so` to the `/usr/lib` would indeed solve the problem as `/usr/lib` is in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by default, however, rather than copying all private libs to the `/usr/lib`, I think it is better to add the path to private libs to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as suggected by knocte.

Comment: I just wanted to know whether copying to /usr/lib would help and then I was going to suggest better solutions such as using LD_LIBRARY_PATH :( never mind I will be faster next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd` mono V8.Net.Console.exe
```

Comment: Arrrgh.... I find it so unintuitive that current directory doesn't belong to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH by default. I've actually added it to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my `.bashrc`, but that only applies to the Terminal, which is why it worked there, but not in the MonoDevelop.

Comment: you're right, I actually think it's a bug (and using LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a workaround), so please go ahead and file it in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: it's a bug in Linux, not in Xamarin :-). MonoDevelop doesn't control how the native library dependencies are resolved.

Comment: not sure about that, the mono runtime should be searching by default in the same folder where the managed assembly is (BTW, we're not talking about Xamarin here, we're talking about Mono; Xamarin is a company)

Comment: It does search the same directory where managed library is and find the native library `libV8_Net_Proxy.so`. However, this library depends on another native library `libv8-x64.so` and this dependency is resolved by Linux, not Mono.

Comment: ah, I see. well, if you place the .so files in /usr/lib, everything would work OOTB I think